# A basic measure theory question on lebesgue integral

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures on a complete separable space $S$. Suppose, for every real-valued continuous function on $S$ we have that
$$\int fd\mu = \int fd\nu$$

does it imply $\mu = \nu$. looks like approximating characteristic functions by continuous functions.

Comment: It is not true. As an example, take $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\nu$ the Lebesgue measure on the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Crostul: Sorry, I forgot to mention that they are probability measures.

Comment: No problem, take the same two inside the space $[0,1]$.

Comment: Are $\mu$ and $\nu$ Borel probability measures, i.e. probability measures defined on the sigma-algebra generated by the open sets?

Comment: @Crostul: I thought it is obvious that the sigma-algebra's are same, only measures are different.

Comment: @StefanHansen: Yes. I thought that is obvoius, so didn't mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ be open and consider
$$
f_n(x)=(n\cdot d(x,U^c))\wedge1,\quad n\geqslant 1.
$$
Then $f_n$ is non-negative and continuous for all $n\geqslant 1$ and $f_n\uparrow \mathbf{1}_U$. Thus by the monotone convergence theorem we have $\mu(U)=\nu(U)$. Since the Borel sigma-algebra is generated by the open sets (which are stable under intersection) we have that $\mu=\nu$.